# jquery slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow

Im new to jquery and the best way to learn a new language is to work with it :d.

so im trying to make a jquery slideshow with thumbnails but i can find out how to make the slide effect :p, so i hope some one can tell me and maybe show some easy to understand code :).

so because i want to make it on my own i dont want to use plugins.

this is what i have http://jsfiddle.net/DYYBe/

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by making a "slide effect?"

Comment: from looking at your example I can't figure out what you want to slide exactly.

Comment: @surreal Dreams @Nick i want to click on the thumbnails and then it should slide on that image i have click on, but i want it to auto slide (with a effect) by it selvf after 10 sec. if you understand me :)

Comment: the code is 1 line right now, so exaclty when do you work with the language?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood correctly what you're after?  I think you're after some sort of slide effect so slide from left for example??

Have you looked at the JQuery documentation?

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide

And as for not using plug-ins, that's all well and good, but why spend hours writing a library that someone's already written, unless you want it to do something the current library doesn't do?

Just a thought.

Welshboy